# Jenkins - Excluded Regions

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Hope you can help :)

I have problem with Excluded Regions in Jenkins.

I'm using Multiple SCM and SVN. In one module I want to retrieve almost everything from directory A without one dir.

Structure below:

```
-> A
    -> dir_B
    -> dir_C
    -> dir_D
    -> file_a.txt
    -> file_b.txt
```

For example, how to avoid downloading dir_C ? 
Now I'm using sth like

```
./dir_C/
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply regex for that folder:

```
dir_C/.*
```

Comment: it does not work